# I wonder why couldn't it be Past Continous in this exercise

Tags: grammar, american-english, past-tense, simple-past

They ............ (get) to the airport as the plane was landing.

I'm doing this exercise of completing with Past Simple, Past Continuous or Past Perfect Simple.

In the answer section I found got as the right answer. I wonder why couldn't it be "Past Continous":

"They were getting to the airport as the plane was landing."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sentences _usually_ have past simple and the continuous construction on either side of 'as'. 'The plane was landing, and/but they were nearing the airport' is more natural for 'double continuous' sentences.

Comment: I assume the sentence uses _get to_ in the sense of _arrive at_ rather than _approach_.

Comment: Both are grammatical. The book has them at the airport while you have them still enroute as the plane was landing.